# How to solve the index in list view is not correct

Tags: flutter

I am using list view + pagination in Flutter to show my response data.

I face the problem when I selected the first list item the details such as id is the other list item id. I have used `print()` to check the id, it always shows the wrong id.

I want to show the details about my image, but it gives me wrong id. So it will show other image.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to define `id` and `title` as variables of the `State` object.
You can pass them as a parameter to the `selectedItem` method instead, the problem is you always set the `id` and `title` to the last item built so it will always navigate with its details instead of the actually selected item.

```dart
class _HomePage State extends State<HomePage > {
GlobalKey<PaginatorState> paginatorGlobalKey = GlobalKey();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
body: return Paginator.listView(
key: paginatorGlobalKey,
pageLoadFuture: sendPagesDataRequest,
pageItemsGetter: listItemsGetterPages,
listItemBuilder: listItemBuilder,
loadingWidgetBuilder: loadingWidgetMaker,
errorWidgetBuilder: errorWidgetMaker,
emptyListWidgetBuilder: emptyListWidgetMaker,
totalItemsGetter: totalPagesGetter,
pageErrorChecker: pageErrorChecker,
scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
);
}

Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
String url = Uri.encodeFull("https://API_URL?page=$page");
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
PagesData pagesData = pagesDataFromJson(response.body);
return pagesData;

List<dynamic> listItemsGetterPages(PagesData pagesData) {
List<Project> list = [];
pagesData.data.forEach((value) {
 list.add(value);
 });
 return list;
}

Widget listItemBuilder(dynamic item, int index) {

 return InkWell(
  onTap: () => selectedItem(item,context), // pass the item iteself in the selectedItem function
  child:  new CachedNetworkImage(
   imageUrl:= item.image,
   placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
   fit:BoxFit.fill,
   ),
);
}

Widget loadingWidgetMaker() {
 return Container(
 alignment: Alignment.center,
 height: 160.0,
 child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
 );
 }

void selectedItem(dynamic item,BuildContext context) { // add a parameter for item
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  DetailsPage.routeName,
  arguments: {
   'id': item.id, // Move the item.id here
   'title': item.title // Move the item.title here
   });    
  }
}
```